# how to create files under /WEB-INF/

Tags: file, servlets, web-inf

I am working on an application that stores files under /WEB-INF/someFolder/. But I dont find the right way to create files under this folder. I did this, but it is not working:

```
        File newFile = new File("/WEB-INF/fileName.xml");
```

When I try to check the creation:

```
        boolean isCreated = newFile.createNewFile();
```

I get :

```
        java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

Please help me doing it in the right way.

**Update:**
I did this workaround, it is working but I dont see that it is performant solution.

```
        ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
        File newFile2 = new File(path+"/fileName.xml");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you applaction have the permissions to write.
you can get the path ues like this:

```
String path=Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("com/youpackage/");
```

Now you get the path which is your class folder path，so you can get the WEB-INF path.
ps: i remember when create file you must writer some content,otherwies it may not create.

Answer (score 9):

You shall use ServletContext.getRealPath(String) and build the entire classpath manually

```
String webInfPath = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF");
```

OR go step by step:

```
ServletConfig scfg= getServletConfig();
ServletContext scxt = scfg.getServletContext();
String webInfPath = sxct.getRealPath("WEB-INF");
```

And than use the webInfPath to create a File object inside WEB-INF

```
File newFile = new File(webInfPath + "/fileName.xml");
```

Comment: Starting with Tomcat 8, you should use `.getRealPath("/WEB-INF")` otherwise you get empty string. Starting path with slash is compatible with other servlet containers.