# How to create file in 'src' (source) directory without specifing the drive

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, src

I know how to create file in Java with a specific path.
I want to create file in the source folder of the project without specifing the drive because it can change from PC to PC.

I tried to use:

```
File targetFile = new File("/src/SavedGames/uploadedFile.xml");
targetFile.createNewFile();
```

with dot before the 'src':

```
File targetFile = new File("./src/SavedGames/uploadedFile.xml");
targetFile.createNewFile();
```

with `\\`:

```
File targetFile = new File("\\src\\SavedGames\\uploadedFile.xml");
targetFile.createNewFile();
```

It doesn't work, it throws exception.

This one works but creates it on my Apache server folder:

```
File targetFile = new File("uploadedFile.xml");
targetFile.createNewFile();
```

This is the hierarchy:
[image]

The code runs on the *LoadGameServlet.java*

Comment: Have you tried `src/SavedGames/uploadedFile.xml`?

Comment: checked now: it tries to create is on c:\myApacheServer\bin\src\SavedGames

Comment: If `src/SavedGames/iploadedFile.xml` doesn't work, check your `Class-Path` in mainfest.mf to make sure it leads to the root of your project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530112/how-to-create-files-under-web-inf

Comment: @SualehFatehi, the solution didn't work for me. I tried the solution: URL path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("src/SavedGames/"); but it still creates it on apache server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching alot I found a way to do it.

```
File targetFile = new File(new File(LoadGameServlet.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParent() + "\\uploadedFile.xml");
String decoderPath = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(targetFile.getPath(), "UTF-8");
String newPath = decoderPath .replaceAll("build\\\\web\\\\WEB-INF\\\\classes\\\\Servlets", "src\\\\java\\\\SavedGames");
targetFile = new File(newPath);
targetFile.createNewFile();
```

I checked it and it works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `System.out.println(targetFile.getAbsolutePath())` to debug where the file would be created, even before creating the actual file.

Comment: Good idea, it creates it on C:\src\SavedGames - there is no such directory.

Comment: You should then create the folder first, or use the `.mkdirs()` function to create it programmatically.

Comment: But I don't want to create it on 'C:' drive because maybe the user already has such folder. I watned to create it on my server SavedGames package.

Comment: Your current folder at runtime seems to be the Apache folder, so all relative paths such as "src/" or "./src/" are relative to that folder. You should make sure that you use the right combination of ".." and relative folders to point the file to the location that you want.

Comment: Also, if you use ".." in your folder names, you can also use the method `targetFile.getCanonicalPath()` to resolve the exact location where the file will be stored to.